# What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a stream of JSON objects that looks somewhat like this:

```
{...}{...}{...}{...}...
```

So basically a concatenated list of JSON objects without any separator.
What's the proper way to deserialize those into an `IEnumerable<T>` using JSON.NET? At the moment I tried something like

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.CheckAdditionalContent = false;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader)) {
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
    reader.Read();
    while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.None) {
        yield return serializer.Deserialize<TResult>(reader);
    }
}
```

But this fails with

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unexpected token while deserializing object: EndObject. Path '', line 1, position 55.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
```

Obviously I need to move the reader after the `Deserialize` call, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think if you change your loop around slightly everything should work:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> ReadJson<TResult>(Stream stream)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
    {
        jsonReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            yield return serializer.Deserialize<TResult>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you must iterate over the `IEnumerable<TResult>` while the `Stream` passed to this method is open:

```
using (var stream = /* some stream */)
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> result = ReadJson<MyClass>(stream);

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.MyProperty);
    }
}
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y2FLuK

Sample on JsonNet site: [Read Multiple Fragments With JsonReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before, but after your fiddle I checked my JSON stream and found that it was not as expected (comma-separated instead of no separator). So this is indeed the right answer, I just had to fix JSON stream.

Comment: what does SupportMultipleContent do?  the documentation doesn't make sense - what does multiple pieces of json content mean?

Comment: @AmbroseLeung: I believe it tells the `JsonTextReader` that multiple JSON fragments are present in the document. The question mentions a single stream of objects (`{}{}{}`), which is why that property is necessary.