# Fast binary serialization/deserialization of ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, performance, serialization, deserialization, expandoobject

I have about 500 Million ExpandoObjects that I want to save to disk and load again. The values are simple types:

- string
- integer
- float
- array of strings
- array of integers
- array of floats
- another ExpandoObject (with one of these simple types as values)

This is my current code to save to disk:

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create), Encoding.UTF8);
foreach(ExpandoObject expandoObject in expandoObjects)
{
    bw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expandoObject));
}
bw.Close();
```

and this is my code to load from disk:

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open));
while (br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length)
{
    ExpandoObject expandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(br.ReadString());
    expandoObjects.Add(expandoObject);
}
```

Saving to disk is not a time-critical but loading should be faster, if possible. I wonder wether a binary format could accelerate this.

What are your suggestions for a binary approach? Do you think there would be a significant speedup?

Comment: You doing a double step here by serialising to string, then writing as binary. Why not forget about Json and go directly to the binary?

Comment: How would I read from binary and cast to expandoObject if i wrote directly via `bw.Write(expandoObject)`?

Comment: Try this for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738528(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: As @DavidG says don't double serialise, but if you are OK with the json serialisation/deserialisation bit, then just write the json to disk, I suspect it will be smaller than the binary.

Comment: Or, if you want a portable binary format, consider [BSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeFromBsonCollection.htm).

Comment: If you want to see which serialization strategy is fastest, you need to [actually test it](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).  Just guessing is not useful.

Comment: By the way, if you are double-serializing (JSON then Binary) to handle multiple root objects, you can do this directly with Json.NET using [`JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm).  See [What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601594/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-json-net-to-parse-stream-of-json-objects).