# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content:

Tags: c#, arrays, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am facing one strange problem in JSON array while receiving from a server, I tried to deserialize it but it says

I have created a class and tried to deserialize it into that object but, it says

the class is given below.

```
class bundle
{
    public string msgid { get; set; }
    public string messagetype { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }

}
```

> *Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: y. Path '', line 1,
>   position 93.    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type
>   objectType)    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String
>   value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value)    at
>   Listener.Program.LogStatus(Boolean receiving, Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   length) in    at Listener.Program.d__5.MoveNext() in --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
>   at Listener.Program.d__1.MoveNext()*

and the array which I am getting is below,

```
{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"123_119","from":"sam","message":"Hi there, good morning ! "}                                                                                                                            
{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"123_120","from":"sam","message":"how are you?"}                                                                                                                            

{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"6478316959_121","from":"sam","message":"this is msg"} ood morning !"}                                                                                                                            
{"messagetype":"ping"}g","msgid":"6478316959_121","from":"sam","message":"you are crazy"} orning ! "}
```

it is unexpected token at the end.

Comment: That JSON is invalid, it has multiple root elements.  Try pasting it into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see the problem.  To read a sequence of JSON root elements, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601594/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-json-net-to-parse-stream-of-json-objects

Comment: I know it has unexpected token at the end, but when I try  to deserialize it, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your JSON, I realize it has more problems than just being a stream of root objects.  For this line: `{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"6478316959_121","from":"sam","message":"this is msg"} ood morning !"}`, it appears somebody tried to overwrite a line in the file, and failed to overwrite it completely.  Are you sure your JSON is really that bad?

Comment: yes it, I am trying to figure out how to deserialize it to class object, but it keeps throwing me same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After alot of work, I came up with this:

```
string final = string.Empty;
string name = encoder.GetString(buffer);
char []arr = name.ToArray();

boolean bln = true;
foreach (char item in arr)
{
    if (bln)
    {
        if (item == '}')
        {
            final += item.ToString();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            final += item.ToString();
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(final);
```

which will truncate the rest of the characters.

Answer (score 1):

all of array item keys must placed in your finally class by same name, change your class to this and test it again:

```
class bundle
{
    public string msgid { get; set; }
    public string messagetype { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }

}
```

elso you can convert your JSON array by tools like this: [JSON2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: tried it, but doesn't work, the error is still there :(

Comment: do you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bundle>(JsonStr);` to parse it? if your array contain 4 items, change it to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<bundle>>(JsonStr);` and make your array to valid JSON array => `var allItems = [{},{}];`

Comment: That's an object he's trying to deserialize, not an array. He just needs to strip out the extra junk that doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Json is invalid and because you have multiple root element you need to deserialize to `List<bundle>`.

```
{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"123_119","from":"sam","message":"Hi there, good morning ! "}                                                                                                                            
{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"123_120","from":"sam","message":"how are you?"}                                                                                                                            

{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"6478316959_121","from":"sam","message":"this is msg. Good morning !"}                                                                                                                            
{"messagetype":"ping","msgid":"6478316959_121","from":"sam","message":"you are crazy morning ! "}
```

Comment: tried it, when I receive the JSON array, it is getting appended with first message from first array,  at the end like this. 

{"messagetype":"chatmsg","msgid":"6478316959_121","from":"sam","message":"this is msg"} ood morning !"}

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Newtonsoft; and in my example the serialize worked after I surrounded my entire JSON with these `{` `}`

Hope this helps someone.