# Parse a string containing several json objects into something more convenient

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

The crux of the problem here is that I don't know any C#, yet find myself adding a feature to some test infrastructure which happens to be written in C#. I suspect this question is entirely trivial and beg your patience in answering. My colleagues who originally wrote this stuff are all out of the office.

I am parsing a string representing one or more json objects. So far I can get the first object, but can't work out how to access the remainder.

```
public class demo
{
public void minimal()
{
    // Note - the input is not quite json! I.e. I don't have 
    // [{"Name" : "foo"}, {"Name" : "bar"}]
    // Each individual object is well formed, they just aren't in
    // a convenient array for easy parsing.
    // Each string representation of an object are literally concatenated.

    string data = @"{""Name"": ""foo""} {""Name"" : ""bar""}";

    System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader = 
       JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data),
       new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

    System.Xml.Linq.XElement root = XElement.Load(jsonReader);
    Assert.AreEqual(root.XPathSelectElement("//Name").Value, "foo");

    // The following clearly doesn't work
    Assert.AreEqual(root.XPathSelectElement("//Name").Value, "bar");
}
}
```

I'm roughly at the point of rolling enough of a parser to work out where to split the string by counting braces but am hoping that the library support will do this for me.

The ideal end result is a sequential datastructure of your choice (list, vector? don't care) containing one `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` for each json object embedded in the string.

Thanks!

edit: Roughly viable example, mostly due to George Richardson - I'm playing fast and loose with the type system (not sure dynamic is available in C#3.0), but the end result seems to be predictable.

```
public class demo
{
    private IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>
            DeserializeObjects(string input)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (var strreader = new StringReader(input))
        {
            using (var jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(strreader))
            {
                jsonreader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
                while (jsonreader.Read())
                {
                    yield return (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
                                  serializer.Deserialize(jsonreader);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void example()
    {
        string json = @"{""Name"": ""foo""} {""Name"" : ""bar""} {""Name"" : ""baz""}";
        var objects = DeserializeObjects(json);

        var array = objects.ToArray();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, array.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(array[0]["Name"].ToString(), "foo");
        Assert.AreEqual(array[1]["Name"].ToString(), "bar");
        Assert.AreEqual(array[2]["Name"].ToString(), "baz");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Also, is your data correct? Should it be: `"[{""Name"": ""foo""}, {""Name"" : ""bar""}]"` ?

Comment: "Correct" might be overstating it. I don't have an array of objects to parse, I have N objects literally concatenated together

Comment: The problem is you're using an XML parser to read JSON data.  Use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: That did strike me as strange, but I can't find an alternative without installing extra dependencies which I'd much rather avoid. I suspect the root problem is actually that I'm not reading strictly valid json, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Use http://json2csharp.com/ to get class/classes then Json.net to serialize it.

Comment: You can parse multiple non array items using the property SupportMultipleContent -> http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm

Then you can dump the xml for the correct json parsers

Comment: You can try using the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET 3.5 and later if your data is valid JSON.  It's _certainly_ not valid XML.

Comment: @PaulSwetz Installing newtonsoft's json library turned out to be trivial, thanks. SupportMultipleContent is exactly what I'm looking for too. I haven't managed to wire up an example yet, but am feeling optimistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for your actual deserialization needs. The big problem I see here is that your json data is just being concatenated together which means you are going to have to extract each object from the string. Luckily json.net's `JsonReader` has a `SupportMultipleContent` property which does just this

```
public void Main()
{
    string json = @"{""Name"": ""foo""} {""Name"" : ""bar""} {""Name"" : ""baz""}";
    IEnumerable<dynamic> deserialized = DeserializeObjects(json);
    string name = deserialized.First().Name; //name is "foo"
}

IEnumerable<object> DeserializeObjects(string input)
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var strreader = new StringReader(input)) {
        using (var jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(strreader)) {
            jsonreader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
            while (jsonreader.Read()) {
                yield return serializer.Deserialize(jsonreader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to hack it, json reader supports the prop SupportMultipleContent  which is used exactly for this situation.

Comment: @Paul Wow yeah thats great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601594/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-json-net-to-parse-stream-of-json-objects has everything we need here. I will update my answer

Comment: Linked question is great! It will probably be a duplicate once I can work out what the code actually means. "Stream of json objects" is a good description too

Comment: @JonChesterfield I have updated my above answer with this new information

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson This looks great - it's way beyond my knowledge of C# though, so I'm going to have to take some time to work out what's going on. Really helpful, thank you