# Using OPENJSON when the source is not formatted as a set

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've got a very large source JSON file with a large collection of entities not formatted as a set; no encapsulating square bracket and no comma delimiter between each entity. So imagine that instead of '[{},{}]' I've got '{}{}'. I'm trying to query it with OPENJSON but in the current structure I only get the first record.

Here's what I'm effectively doing:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
 N'  
    {  
    "Id":1
    } 
    {  
    "Id":2
    }  
'  

SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON (@json)  
WITH (Id INT)
```

And I get a single result which is record 1. Is there a way of querying the structure as it stands or am I pretty much up for trying to reformat the source?

Comment: Problem is that that isn't actually JSON. It's close, but not quite. I would suggest pushing it through a bit of reformatting first, such as adding the square brackets, and replacing every { with ,{ (and then using STUFF to remove the second character where you'll have a rogue comma.

Comment: Just as a side note I think `@json` should be  `NVARCHAR(MAX)` ;).

Answer (score 2):

As per Rob's suggestion you're going to need to do a bit of preformatting.

And as per his suggestion...this will work if the "json" is as you describe. I wouldn't expect it to perform that well across large amounts of text.  If you're JSON is more complex than this and contains nested entities I'd skip T-SQL and use C# or PowerShell

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
 N'  
    {  
    "Id":1
    } 
    {  
    "Id":2
    }  
'  

SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON (
    (SELECT '[' + STUFF(REPLACE(@json, '{', ',{'),  CHARINDEX('{', @json), 1, '') + ']')
    )
WITH (Id INT)
```

If you can do that preformatting on your import into the DB in anyway that would likely be a better approach overall

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks similar to the one discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601594/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-json-net-to-parse-stream-of-json-objects), so maybe the same solution could be applied also in your case (I would deserialize your "json-like data" with JSON.NET as described there and then use it directly or serialize it again and then use OPENJSON)

Answer (score 0):

OPENJSON needs valid JSON. You can check if the value is valid using the ISJSON function.

We had a similar issue in the sense we had a valid JSON string buried within a larger string, which meant the whole string was not valid JSON. We had to find and extract the valid JSON within it. So we created a computed column to do this. Our JSON process then picked up the valid JSON from the computed column using OPENJSON. You just have to weigh up whether to persist or not.