# Json.Net how to read data from stream which as one json object per line

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an external data file that I am reading in for processing compressed in a gz file (hosted in S3).  It contains json objects (1 per line and millions of lines per file) as mocked up data example below

```
{"a":"v1","b":"v2"}
{"a":"v3","b":"v2"}
```

I am using the following code to process this

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(data, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(decompressionStream))
    {
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    var o = serializer.Deserialize<DataObject>(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DataObject is just a POCO data object to map the data into.  First iteration works perfectly however I get an exception on the second execution on reader.Read().

```
Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content
```

I think this could be due to the linefeed at the end of each json object but not sure how to resolve.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Set `reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;` as shown in [What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26601594) and [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063).

Comment: Thanks dbc - you are right and I think we found that article at exactly the same time :).  Appreciate the response